# Append the same value multiple times to a list

Tags: python, list, append

To make my program more beautiful instead of ugly, I am trying to find a more pythonic way of adding a single value multiple times to a list. I now use a loop, but I create a variable I do not use.

```
l = []; n = 5; v = 0.5

for i in xrange(n):
    l.append(v)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: That would define l, not append to it. If l already holds values they would be lost.

Comment: Thanks all, Lattyware for the most general answer, although I will use Boo's solution in this specific case ;)

Answer (score 51, accepted):

To add v, n times, to l:

```
l += n * [v]
```

Answer (score 12):

Try using `list.extend` and the multiply operator for lists

```
l.extend([v] * n)
```

Comment: Note that this will produce a list of `[v, v, v...]` `n` times, which is fine if the value is immutable, but could cause unexpected behaviour if the value is mutable and you expect them to be independent.

Comment: Note that if `v` is a mutable object then it can lead to undesired results.

Comment: In case *you know that `v` is mutable* you should use `[v.copy()] * n` instead.

Comment: @NilsWerner That will not work. It will copy the value once, and then make a list of `n` references to that copy.

Comment: Oh, you are right. Wouldn't have expected that...

Comment: @NilsWerner It's because the value is evaluated as a literal, then placed into a list. By the time you are multiplying that list, it's just a list containing a reference to an object - Python doesn't know how to copy that item even if it wanted to (`__copy__()` is a good guess, but there is no guarantee it's implemented or possible). The issue is expecting `*` to re-evaluate the expression, which it doesn't do. It just copies a reference. It's more obvious if you think of it as `new = v.copy()` `[new] * n` - which is exactly the same.

Answer (score 10):

The most general answer to this is to use [`list.extend()`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types) and a [generator expression](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pShL9DCSIUw):

```
l.extend(generate_value() for _ in range(n))
```

This will add a value `n` times. Note that this will evaluate `generate_value()` each time, side-stepping issues with mutable values that other answers may have:

```
>>> [[1]] * 5
[[1], [1], [1], [1], [1]]
>>> _[0].append(1)
>>> _
[[1, 1], [1, 1], [1, 1], [1, 1], [1, 1]]
>>> [[1] for _ in range(5)]
[[1], [1], [1], [1], [1]]
>>> _[0].append(1)
>>> _
[[1, 1], [1], [1], [1], [1]]
```

When using the multiplication method, you end up with a list of n references to the same list. When you change it, you see the change in every element of the list - as they are all the same.

When using a generator expression or list comprehension, a new list is created for each sub-item, so each item is a different value. Modifying one only affects that one.

Obviously, in your example, the values are immutable, so this doesn't matter - but it's worth remembering for different cases, or if the values *might not* be immutable.

Comment: As an alternative to `generate_value()`; in most cases you can also use `copy.deepcopy()`

Comment: @LieRyan 'In most cases' is strong - In most cases, you'll probably just be putting a constructor call or a literal there, so copying wouldn't be necessary. `copy.deepcopy()` also only works on things that implement `__deepcopy__()`, which isn't a guarantee. `generate_value()` is a place-holder designed to show that anything that produces a value could be used - including, but not limited to, `copy.deepcopy()`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
n = 5
v = 0.5
l = [v]*n
```